# Microsoft Query in Excel SQL Criteria Variant Type causes OLE error

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, criteria

```
Public Sub SQLSelect(connection As String, range1 As Excel.range, _
range2 As Excel.range, Optional range1name As String, Optional range2name As String,_
 Optional varparameter As Variant, Optional varcriteria As Variant, _
Optional varnot As Variant, Optional sdestination As String,_
 Optional srangename As String, Optional sqlrange As String)

Dim sselect As String
Dim cn As ADODB.connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cm As ADODB.Command
Dim pm As ADODB.Parameter
Dim iiterator As Integer
Dim varcriteriterator As Variant

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
Set cm = New ADODB.Command

sselect = "SELECT " & range1name & ".ENTITYREF, SUM(" & range1name & ".AMT), SUM(" & range2name & ".AMT) FROM " & range1name & " " & range1name & " INNER JOIN " & range2name & " " & range2name & " ON " & range1name & ".ENTITYREF" & " = " & range2name & ".ENTITYREF WHERE "

cn.Open (connection)

With cm
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    For iiterator = 0 To UBound(varparameter)
        If iiterator = 0 Then
            sselect = sselect & range1name & "." & varparameter(iiterator) & " = ? "
        Else
            sselect = sselect & " AND " & range1name & "." & varparameter(iiterator) & " = ? "
        End If

        If Not CStr(varcriteria(iiterator)) = varcriteria(iiterator) Then
            For Each varcriteriterator In varcriteria

            Set pm = .CreateParameter(varparameter(iiterator), adNumeric, adParamInput)

                If varnot(iiterator) = 0 Then
                    pm.Value = varcriteriaiterator
                ElseIf varnot(iiterator) = 1 Then
                    pm.Value = "NOT" & varcriteriaiterator
                End If

            cm.Parameters.Append pm

            Next

        Else

            Set pm = .CreateParameter(varparameter(iiterator), adNumeric, adParamInput)

            If varnot(iiterator) = 0 Then
                    pm.Value = varcriteria(iiterator)
            ElseIf varnot(iiterator) = 1 Then
                    pm.Value = "NOT" & varcriteria(iiterator)
            End If

            .Parameters.Append pm

        End If
    Next iiterator
End With

sselect = sselect & "GROUP BY " & range1name & ".ENTITYREF HAVING(((Count(" & range1name & ".AMT))>1) AND ((Count(" & range2name & ".AMT))>1));"

cm.CommandText = sselect

Set rs = cm.Execute

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SourcePivot").range(sdestination).CopyFromRecordset rs

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SourcePivot").range(sdestination, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SourcePivot").range(sdestination).End(xlDown).Offset(, 2)).Name = srangename

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interface").range(sqlrange).Value = sselect
```

The above code is intended to create a query within an excel workbook which can be passed two ranges of data and create a functional SQL statement through microsoft query to draw the information into a destination range. VarNot is an array of 1&0's which mark whether the matching criteria should be a NOT, and the SQL range is a destination cell which houses the query for troubleshooting.

I have received the following error:

> Multi-Step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB Status
>   value, if available. No work was done.

This is after the code executed properly and create a well-formed query:

```
SELECT Case1.ENTITYNUM, SUM(Case1.AMT), SUM(Case2.AMT) _
FROM Case1 Case1 INNER JOIN Case2 Case2 ON Case1.ENTITYNUM = Case2.ENTITYNUM _
WHERE Case1.Code = ?  AND Case1.YEAR = ? _
GROUP BY Case1.ENTITYNUM HAVING(((Count(Case1.AMT))>1) AND ((Count(Case2.AMT))>1));
```

I will end passing the module a variety of criteria and parameters, but the parameters are, at this point, exclusive an array of text strings. The criteria are arrays of strings and ranges, which I believe is causing the issue.

I would appreciate any help in solving the error and successfully parameterizing this query with an array that may contain a string or variant range of cells.

Comment: Are Case1.Code and Year numeric?

Comment: Case1.Code is text, and Year is numeric.

Comment: Try casting Case1.Year to a string (CStr(Case1.Year)) or casting the second parameter to CInt, ex. CInt(?) .